# Generating Tests in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have some JavaScript that I am testing with [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/). At this time, one of my suites look like this:

```
var library = require('../library');

describe('My App -', function() {
   afterEach(function(done) {
      // some clean up code goes here
      library.cleanUp(done);
      done();       
   });

   describe('Test Operation 1 -', function() {
      beforeEach(function(done) {
         library.init(done);
      });

      it('should load fine', function() {
        if (library) {
          expect(true).toBe(true);
        } else {
          expect(false).toBe(true);
        }
      });

      var parameters = [1, 8.24, -1];
      var results = [5, 4, 0];

      // [TODO]: Create tests here
   });   
});
```

Is there a way for me generate specs from my `parameters` and `results` arrays? In other words, at runtime, I would essentially like to dynamically run:

```
it('should be 5 when parameter is 1', function(done)) {
  var result = library.calculate(1);
  expect(result).toBe(5);
  done();
});

it('should be 4 when parameter is 8.24', function(done) {
  var result = library.calculate(8.24);
  expect(result).toBe(4);
  done();
});

it('should be 0 when parameter is -1', function(done) {
  var result = library.calculate(-1);
  expect(result).toBe(0);
  done();
});
```

I do NOT want the following:

```
it('should test the parameters', function() {
  for (var i=0; i<parameters.length; i++) {
    var result = library.calculate(parameters[i]);
    expect(results[i]).toBe(result);
  }
});
```

I am trying to figure out how to dynamically generate some tests at runtime.

Thank you!

Comment: If your problem with the loop is the messages aren't specific enough, you might want to look into jasmine custom messages (library on github). It allows you to have a custom/exact message but within the loop.

Comment: `it` can be placed inside `for` loop, as a result you'll have multiple specs with single expectation in each of them, instead of one spec with multiple expectations (like it is in your last code sample). Title for `it` can also be dynamic and created depending on current loop iteration.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov is there any way to put an `it` inside of an `eval`? If so, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on @Michael Radionov's comment you can dynamically generate test cases using a for loop.Sample code for dynamic test case generation is provided below:

```
describe("Generating Tests with Jasmine",function(){
        //var parameters = [1, 8.24, -1];
        //var results = [5, 4, 0];

        var tests = [
            {parameter: 1,       result: 5},
            {parameter: 8.24,    result: 4},
            {parameter: -1, result: 0}
        ];

        tests.forEach(function(test) {
            it('should be ' + test.result + ' when parameter is '+test.parameter, function(done) {
                var result = library.calculate(test.parameter);
                expect(result).toBe(test.result);
                done();
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: Can I also add them asynchronously?

Comment: This worked great in cleaning up testing the links between triggers and listenTos in a backbone app.